# Pass props from child to parent react navigation

Tags: javascript, react-native, router, react-navigation

I am using `react-navigation`. I am passing `props`from a `react-native component` to the `modal` from `react-navigation` which is opened on a tap.

```
export default class SomeComp extends Component {
...

render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props;
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={navigate("Modal", {data: ..., ...})}
        ..../>
       )
    }
}
```

Inside the `modal` I access the `goBack()` function which closes the `modal`, as well as the `props` passed through `SomeComp`

```
export default class Modal extends Component {
...

render() {
    const { data, ... } = this.props.navigation.state.params;
    const { goBack } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
        <View>
            <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={goBack()}
            ..../>
            <Text>
               {data, ...}
            </Text>
        </View>
       )
    }
}
```

What I wonder is, whether its possible or not to pass `props` *down* from `Modal` to `SomeComp`, *without* using `redux`.
In a "normal" `react-native parent-child component` I would do that with a simple `callback`. However, that does not work here, because the `modal` is defined in the `router`, hence, completely independent from `SomeComp`. Its only called from there...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is really simple solution to pass back props to parent component on `goBack()`.

You can pass an extra prop containing function to Modal and right before calling `goBack()` or in `componentWillUnmount` you can call that function.

**Example**

```
export default class SomeComp extends Component {
...

onGoBack = (someDataFromModal) => {
  console.log(someDataFromModal);
}

render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props;
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={navigate("Modal", {data: ..., ..., onGoBack: this.onGoBack})}
        ..../>
       )
    }
}
```

---

```
export default class Modal extends Component {
...

componentWillUnmount() {
  if(this.props.navigation.state.params.onGoBack) {
    this.props.navigation.state.params.onGoBack('I fired from Modal!');
  } 
}

render() {
    const { data, ... } = this.props.navigation.state.params;
    const { goBack } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
        <View>
            <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={goBack()}
            ..../>
            <Text>
               {data, ...}
            </Text>
        </View>
       )
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh dear... I didnt think about passing a `function` as a `prop` through `params`... thanks!

Comment: You'll get a warning if you pass functions as parameters because they are not serializable. There's more information here and how to turn off the warning https://reactnavigation.org/docs/troubleshooting/#i-get-the-warning-non-serializable-values-were-found-in-the-navigation-state