# Deep Navigate Without Instantiating Intermediate Components

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I want to reset a stack and navigate a couple of steps. This pattern works fine:

```
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation'

const resetAction = NavigationActions.reset({
  index: 1,
  actions: [
    NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'List'}),
    NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Detail', params: {id: theId})
  ]
})
this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction)
```

But there's one problem. I don't want to render the List. The Detail page will fetch the item from the server based on `theId`. However, before that, the List will fetch all the items from the server, which is pointless and wasteful.

I need for the Back button on the Detail to work, meaning go back to the List. Is there a way to put List into the stack without presently instantiating and rendering it causing extra load on my server?

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution that I can think of is to send a parameter to the list component and checking the parameter before making the request or rendering.

**Example**

```
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation'

const resetAction = NavigationActions.reset({
  index: 1,
  actions: [
    NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'List', params: { reset: true }}),
    NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Detail', params: {id: theId})
  ]
})
this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction)
```

---

```
class List extends Component {
  // ...
  componentDidMount() {
    //example for control
    let list = [];

    if(this.props.navigation.state.params.reset !== true) {
      // populate list
    }
    this.setState({ list });
  }
  // ...
}
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that when the user hits the back button, the list is empty because the List component must still render, except without data. I think in my case I will stick with the default behavior and let the fetch happen. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @TimScott Well that is a bit confusing then. You eventually want the list to be rendered then since there is a chance to `goBack()`. Then you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46796224/2315280) for a complimentary approach to this answer.