# react-native componentWillAppear doesn't fire?

Tags: react-native

I have a Home screen as the root of my stack navigator.  I tried to add a `componentWillAppear` function to my Home.js react component but it doesn't fire when I return to that screen from my contact screen by pressing the back button.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {StackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import Contact from './Contact';

class Home extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {title:'Home'};

  componentWillAppear()
  {
      console.log('hello');
  }
  render()
  {
     return <View></View>;
  }
}

let Router = 
{
  Home: {screen: Home},
  Contact:{screen:Contact}
}

const Navigator = StackNavigator(Router);
export default Navigator;
```

Is there another event handler that will always fire every time my Home screen becomes visible when you've returned from a child screen of a Stacked Navigator?

Comment: That is an expected behavior I believe. When you push a screen, the previous screen doesn't un-mount so going back doesn't fire anything on the previous screen.

Comment: is there anything like a componentOnFocus() or componentOnVisible() or something like that?

Comment: I don't think there is. If you need to do something on previous screen there is 2 options you can use. First option is to use redux or similar package and fire an action to update the previous components props or second option is to use a custom back button that does something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46796224/2315280) and then `this.props.navigation.goBack()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per bennygenel comment:

> I don't think there is. If you need to do something on previous screen
>   there is 2 options you can use. First option is to use redux or
>   similar package and fire an action to update the previous components
>   props or second option is to use a custom back button that does
>   something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46796224/2315280) and then this.props.navigation.goBack()