# What is react-native component doing when the component is in background

Tags: react-native

What is react-native component doing when the component is in background?

And What will react-native do when component re-active to foreground?

Like Page A navigate to Page B.
And Page B back to Page A.What happened to A and B?

Is there any ui update like onResume on Android or something?

Edit:

I have a TabNavagation with four tab.One of the tabs renders an Android UI Component which is a custom frameLayout(a listview is in the frameLayout).

When the frameLayout first rendered, the listview position is not correct(position is -4 item height).But when I navigate to a child page and goback, I found that the frameLayout is correct now and does't enter any android lifecycle.

So I'm wondering is it doing something background?

Comment: The life cycle methods of the component can be found in the documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debug many many times, I found that it is the `react-navigation`.

Four tabs in homepage with bottom tabbar.When I enter a child page with `navigationOptions:{header:null}`, the bottom bar is gone. And when I goback from the child page, the bottom bar has back meanwhile and the whole view has corrected.Seems the whole view is re-draw?So I called `view.requestLayout()` in `createViewInstance()`.So the final result is the view need to requestLayout manual.

UPDATE:
answer top is not totally correct.The final problem is the custom view should measure self in its requestLayout.
I found the answer in https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4990

```
@Override
public void requestLayout() {
    super.requestLayout();
    post(measureAndLayout);
}

private final Runnable measureAndLayout = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(getWidth(), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
                MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(getHeight(), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
        layout(getLeft(), getTop(), getRight(), getBottom());
    }
};
```

And thanks for your answers.@bennygenel  @Jouke

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell without detail information on what type of navigation you are using but I can explain it considering you are using common navigation packages.

If your navigation is some sort of stack navigation, when you navigate/push a new screen to view the previous screen lays under the stack and doesn't un-mount. It is much like dealing a deck of card to a pile. It doesn't re-render unless the props or state of that specific component changes. When you navigate back the new screen un-mounts and the previous screen shows back.

Common packages lets you to pass props to the next screen and if you need to re-render a previous component a easy hack to achieve this by sending a function from the previous component and running it on [`componentWillUnmount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillunmount) life-cycle event of the current screen. I explained this sort of usage in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46796224/2315280).

Comment: Maybe it is not about react lifecycle? I have updated the description.Thank u.

Comment: Is TabNavigation from react-navigation package? If it is the tabs are rendered single time when the navigation first rendered. This is the default behavior. If the props or state doesn't change tabs do not re-render.

Comment: e...It's not a re-render thing.I re-render the component manual but the list still in a wrong position.I just don't know why I enter a child page and goback, the list is corrected.