# React Native Stacknavigator goBack() with props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm made some system with React Native.(no redux)

Component Structure is below.

```
[StackNavigator]

Parent(Board) -> Child(Comment)
```

If I click Comment's button,

It will call `this.props.navigation.goBack()`

Board Component has `Refresh()` function, So If goBack() detected,

I want to execute Refresh() automatically.

To implement it, I set state `backRefresh: false` on Board Compoenent.

My scenario is here.

1. (Comment) goBack with props(backRefresh: true)
2. (Board) Detect whether backRefresh is true or false
3. (Board) If backRefresh is true, execute Refresh()

I want to know is it possible pass props to parent with goBack() function?

Comment: Check [this](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/1416#issuecomment-300489310), by passing the `function` from `parent component` to the `child` and call it when the back button is pressed.Hope it helps!

Comment: @PritishVaidya Is this the best way for my case?

Comment: If the `component` is for a `single`use, this would be the optimum solution, else you may need to listen for the states on `route` change,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass props from child to parent react navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46796087/pass-props-from-child-to-parent-react-navigation)