# React Native Pass array from child to parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, components

I have two components and i am trying to pass array state on back button to parent component but its not showing any data.

Screen1.js

```
class Screen1 extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        selectedRecord: []
    };
}

updateData = (data) => {
    this.setState({selectedRecord: data})
}


render() {
    const {container} = styles;
    return (
        <View style={container}>
            <Button onPress={() => alert(this.state.selectedRecord)}>
                Show Value
            </Button>
        </View>
    );
}
}
```

I created a method on Screen2.js

```
class Screen2 extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        record: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    };
}

backStock() {
    this.props.navigation.state.params.updateData(this.state.record);
    this.props.navigation.goBack()
}


render() {
    const {container} = styles;
    return (
        <View style={container}>
            <Button onPress={() => this.backStock()} transparent>
                <Icon name='arrow-back'/>
            </Button>
        </View>
    );
}
}
```

And backStock() method runs when i click on my back button. But when i tried to print value in console it was empthy. Am i missing something, is there a smooth way to pass states onback method?

Comment: Show please complete code of your components.

Comment: I followed these steps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46796087/pass-props-from-child-to-parent-react-navigation

Comment: I checked on screen2 data is showing. But not passing through screen2 to screen1 with goBack() method

Comment: You cannot pass data with `goBack()`. What you are doing is right. You are calling the method with data as params passed from screen1 in screen2. Please post the code you have written for building Screen1 and Screen2

Comment: Now i added my whole code, Kindly guide