# Execute a callback when navigating

Tags: react-native

I've got a Home screen with a list of content that I pull from a server. I want that when in my application we `this.props.navigation.navigate('home')` from elsewhere, a callback is called in Home that will pull new data from server.

This simple task seems very painful. Indeed `componentDidMount` doesn't work. I don't know what to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass props from child to parent react navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46796087/pass-props-from-child-to-parent-react-navigation)

Comment: Using a callback in a navigate object param is that the only solution ? Why ComponentWillMont, ...DidMount are not called when i navigate to a screen that has been already created ?

Comment: The answer lays in the question. They are not called in an already created component because the component is already created (Mounted). There is another option. You can use [listeners](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#addlistener-subscribe-to-updates-to-navigation-lifecycle)

Comment: This seems better i will try it thanks

Comment: @bennygenel That do the job ! i would like to make your answer like accepted could you make an answer that i can accept ?