# react navigation performing function when returning from the screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm using react navigation to navigate between my screens. I have a main screen (Main.js) and a screen called (Favorites.js).

I use this function to go to my favorites screen.

```
 _btnFavoritos = async () => {

    const movies = this.state.myFavorites;
    console.log("Abrir Favoritos");
    console.log(movies);
    this.props.navigation.navigate('screenFavoritos', { movies: movies });

};
```

how is it possible to have a callback function so that when I exit my favorites screen and return to my main screen I trigger a function capable of updating my main?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass props from child to parent react navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46796087/pass-props-from-child-to-parent-react-navigation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of topic but I would remove the `async` keyword from `_btnFavoritos` unless your function has more code that requires it and you simply didn't add it here

The solution:

```
 _btnFavoritos = () => {    
    const movies = this.state.myFavorites;
    console.log("Abrir Favoritos");
    console.log(movies);
    this.props.navigation.navigate('screenFavoritos',
            {
                    movies: movies,
                    updateMain: () => this.updateMain()
            });
};

updateMain = () => {
    // Sample update logic
    fetch('https://someEndpoint.com')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => this.setState({ movies: json })
    .catch(err => console.warn(err.message)
}
```

Favorites.js

```
componentWillUnmount(){
    const { params } = this.props.navigation.state
    params && params.updateMain && params.updateMain() // Checking that the function was passed down
                                               // as a navigation prop before executing
}
```