# How to share or to recive some data from second screen In React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have 2 screens, my Home Screen

```
class Home extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        myDebts: 745.8455656,
        debts: 1745.54555
    }
}

addFriendsHandler = () => {
    Alert.alert('You tapped the button!')
}

render () {
    return (
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
            <Header
                text={"Splitwise"} />
            <Debts
                myDebts={this.state.myDebts}
                debts={this.state.debts}/>
            <Buttons text={"+ ADD FRIENDS ON SPLITWISE"}
                     clicked={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("AddFriend")}/>
        </View>
    )
  }
}

export default Home
```

and my second Screen

```
class AddFriendPage extends Component{
state = {
    name: ''
}

addFriendHandler = () => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate("MainPage")
}

render() {
    return (
        <View>
            <Header text={"Add a friend"}/>
            <Sae
                label={'Your friends name'}
                labelStyle={{ color: '#47AE4f' }}
                iconClass={FontAwesomeIcon}
                iconName={'pencil'}
                iconColor={"#47AE4f"}
                inputStyle={{ color: '#000' }}
                onBlur={(e) => this.setState({name: e.nativeEvent.text})}
            />
            <Buttons text={"+ ADD FRIEND"}
                     disable={this.state.name === ''}
                     clicked={this.addFriendHandler}/>
        </View>
    )
 }
}
```

and my Navigator

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
     render() {
        return (
        <AppStackNavigator />
         );
        }
       }

      const AppStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
      MainPage: Home,
      AddFriend: AddFriendScreen
    })
```

I want to send a function to the AddFriendPage screen from Home screen, and inside that function i want to get value from input and return the name back into Home screen, but unfortunately i have no idea how to share data between 2 screens

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass props from child to parent react navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46796087/pass-props-from-child-to-parent-react-navigation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/params.html#docsNav

You want to pass params during navigation:

```
() => this.props.navigation.navigate("AddFriend", {name: "Alan"})
```

Then in the parent method (if you want to display it, you could just put it in render):

```
const name = this.props.navigation.getParam(name, null)
```

If null, you know that the screen was reached from a different screen, and can handle that case normally. You can add whatever params you want.

Comment: i want to pass value from first screen into second screen

Comment: The same thing works both ways. You just add the params you want in the navigate call. I'll edit to reflect that

Comment: I tried like this this.props.navigation.navigate("AddFriend", {formVal: 'someval'} (first screen) and in the second screen <Text>{this.props.navigation.getParam(formVal, null)}</Text> and it does not work

Comment: yeah, exactly (plus a closing parenthesis)

Comment: And then you get the val out wherever it is needed in the component using `this.props.navigation.getParam`

Comment: i did the same thing and got an error ("Can't find variable: formVal) in the second screen, what is wrong?

Comment: Oh thank you very match now it's working, is it possible to send an object from first and then the second screen will add some data into an object and return it back (modified version) and is it a value copy or reference copy?

Comment: It's a value copy. If you'd like to send data and then modify it, you might want to pass two parameters. One of them will be the data (state of first screen), and the second one will be a function that will update the first screen's state when called.

Comment: You can always pass the changed data back through navigation as well - same as passing it forward.